# How to exclude "False" from being equaled to 0s in Python list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a list that is the copy of the input list minus the 0s.

**Input list:**

```
input = ['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9, 0, 0, 0, False, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Code:**

```
[i for i in input if i != 0]
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b', None, 'c', 'd', 1, 1, 3, [], 1, 9, {}, 9]
```

The problem is that in the input list there is a "False" value that is not considered different than 0s therefore it does not appear in the output. How do I modify the code so that the "False" gets included in the output?

Answer (score 3):

You could add an extra check for `i is False`:

```
[i for i in input if i != 0 or i is False]
```

You haven't said what how you want to handle other numbers that are equal to zero, like the float `0.0` or `Decimal('0')`. This answer assumes that you want to exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

`False` is very much like `0`, since `bool` is a subtype of `int`. You can filter out values that are only both `0` and *exactly* an `int`, though:

```
[i for i in input if i != 0 or type(i) != int]
```

This of course keeps things that are not integers, like `0.0`, `Decimal(0)`, etc..

In Python 2, it’ll need to be `or type(i) not in (int, long)`, but don’t use Python 2.

Comment: This would include `0.0`, which might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Alasdair: Then again, it might be what the OP wants. =)

Comment: You're right, it might be what they want. In Python 2 it would include `0L` which is perhaps even more confusing.

Comment: @Alasdair: That’s true. I hope they’re not using Python 2, though.